SOAP XML WSDL with different input and output names in wsdl
I am implementing the OTA_ReadRQ / OTA_ResRetrieveRS message pair and I have hit a problem.  All the other messages I have implemented as paired messages EG: OTA_HotelAvailRQ / OTA_HotelAvailRS
I have tried to create the SOAP WSDL but I get an error from the client;
  [faultcode] => SOAP-ENV:Client [faultstring] => Operation 'OTA_ReadRQ' is not defined in the WSDL for this service
It seems to me I need another definition for OTA_ReadRQ
So I tried duplicating the definitions, but it then said I have a duplicate "name"
I can't find any information on implementing multiple definitions
<definitions 
name="OTA_ResRetrieveRS" 
targetNamespace="xx/resretrieve">`

The wsdl body which defines the elements etc is all fine and validates perfectly.
I can add the entire wsdl if that would help.
I believe the issue is with this section which defines the operation not have a matching definition for OTA_ReadRQ
<message name="ResRetrieveIn">
    <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"/>
    <part name="messagePart" element="import0:OTA_ReadRQ"/>
 </message>
 <message name="ResRetrieveOut">
    <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"/>
    <part name="messagePart" element="import0:OTA_ResRetrieveRS"/>
 </message>
 <portType name="OTA_ResRetrieveInterface">
    <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"/>
    <operation name="ResRetrieve">
        <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"/>
        <input message="tns:ResRetrieveIn"/>
        <output message="tns:ResRetrieveOut"/>
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="OTA_ResRetrieve" type="tns:OTA_ResRetrieveInterface">
    <soap:binding transport="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="ResRetrieve">
        <soap:operation soapAction="/xml:ResRetrieveIn"
   style="document"/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <binding name="OTA_ResRetrieveSoap12" type="tns:OTA_ResRetrieveInterface">
    <soap12:binding transport="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="ResRetrieve">
    <soap12:operation soapAction="xxx/xml:ResRetrieveIn" style="document"/>
        <input>
            <soap12:body use="literal"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap12:body use="literal"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>
<service name="OTA_ResRetrievePort">
    <port name="OTA_ResRetrievePort" binding="tns:OTA_ResRetrieve">
<soap:address location="xxx/hotel_res_retrieve.php"/>
    </port>
    <port name="OTA_ResRetrieveSOAP12Port" binding="tns:OTA_ResRetrieveSoap12">
 <soap12:address location="xxx/hotel_res_retrieve.php"/>
    </port>
</service>

Note: I had to remove all the url references to get this to post

I decided to make the input a simple GET call, problem solved
